# Php calculator answer wont show up in the browser

Tags: php, html, forms, http-post

I've tried to reformat my code as much as i could but im not getting any results showing to the browser. If you could over look and maybe let me know where i went wrong that'll be cool thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
        Untitled Document
    </title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="cal.php" method="$_POST">
        <input type="number" name="value1" placeholder="Enter Number 1" />
        <select name="operator">
          <option value="add">+</option>
          <option value="subtract">-</option>
          <option value="multiply">*</option>
          <option value="divide">/</option>
        </select>
        <input type="number" name="value2" placeholder="Enter Number 2" />
        <input type="submit" value="calculate" />
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

$value1 = $_POST["value1"];
$value2 = $_POST["value2"];
$operator = $_POST["operator"];

if ($operator == "add"){
  $answer = $value1 + $value2;
  echo "<p>Your Answer is: $answer</p>";
}
if ($operator == "subtract"){
  $answer = $value1 - $value2;
  echo "<p>Your Answer is: $answer</p>";
}
if ($operator == "multiply"){
  $answer = $value1 * $value2;
  echo "<p>Your Answer is: $answer</p>";
}
if ($operator == "divide"){
  $answer = $value1 / $value2;
  echo "<p>Your Answer is: $answer</p>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I feel like im getting the code right but not to sure why its not showing the answer in the browser.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The way you're posting in the HTML is incorrect.

```
<form action="cal.php" method="$_POST">
```

Change that to:

```
<form action="cal.php" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
method = "POST"
```

and not

```
method = "$_POST"
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the method of the form to "POST"

Your method is

```
<form action="cal.php" method="$_POST">
```

You have to write it like below

```
<form action="cal.php" method="post">
```

Otherwise your code is fine